# Sending msgs in my crud spring-mvc

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, crud

I am learning `spring-mvc` and I am doing a simple crud.

I have a list of items with a big add button on top of it.
When the user clicks add it will redirect to `/item/add` where the view is a form.

Now, when the user loads a new item I want to show a msg in the list saying something like:

> "Item added successfully"

I noticed that I can do something like:

```
If ( noErrors ) {
 model.addAttribute("Item added successfully");
 return new ModelAndView("redirect:/item", model);
}
```

But I didn't manage to get it working.

Any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use `model.addAttribute(myObject)`, by convention you create a reference in the model to `myObject` keyed by a `String` derived from the name of the class of `myObject`.

For example, if I add an instance of the `MyUser` class: `model.addattribute(myUserInstance)`, then I will be able to access that object on the model by the key `"myUser"`.

Things get tricky when your object is a String, because there's no obvious class to use to generate the key in the model.

Try instead specifying your own key:  `model.addAttribute("statusMessage", "item added successfully")`.  Then in your view, you simply access the object by looking for `statusMessage` on the model: `<c:out value="${statusMessage}" />`